# Powershell get-service runs long when server is down

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a script that we use to check services on remote servers, and email if a service is down.  However, if a server happens to be down while the script is running, it can cause the script to run for a very long time.  Is there any way to speed up the process?  I would like the script to continue until completion.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Also, if there is anything else I can improve on in this script please let me know as I'm new to powershell.  Thanks!

```
#******************  Function To Send E-Mail  ******************#

function sendEmail {

send-mailmessage -to "recipient <admin@mail.com>" -from "sender <admin@mail.com>" `
-subject "$eSubject" `
-body "$eBody" -smtpServer mail.smtpServer.com

}

#******************  Set Variables  ******************#
$erroractionpreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$date = Get-Date

$servicesPath = "C:\path_to_file\services.txt"
$serversPath = "C:\path_to_file\servers.txt"

$services = Get-Content $servicesPath
$servers = Get-Content $serversPath

#******************  Check Services And Send E-Mail  ******************#

foreach ($service in $services) { 

foreach ($server in $servers) 
{

    #Check If Service Exist On Server
    $checkService = Get-Service -ComputerName $server -DisplayName $service

    #If The Service Exists Evaluate Status
    if($checkService)
    {
        if ($checkService.status -notlike "Running")
        {
            #Get Server Last Boot Up Time, Set E-Mail Subject And Body, And Send E-Mail
            $OperatingSystem = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $server
            $LastBootUp = $OperatingSystem.ConvertToDateTime($OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime)
            $eSubject = "$service DOWN on $server"
            $eBody = "$date`r`n$service DOWN on $server`r`nLast bootup time for $server is: $LastBootUp"
            sendEmail
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling `Get-Service`, check to see if the server is online. The following will send one ping to see if the server is online, and if it is not, will skip to the next item in `$servers`. Put this immediately before the line where you call `Get-Service`.

```
if ((Test-Connection -computername $server -quiet -count 1) -eq $false) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alroc!  The script runs for about 01:20 which is a vast improvement from before.  Would it be wise to add an email notification for the test-connection when the connection fails?  If so, where would I put that in the current script?

Comment: If my response solved your problem, please mark it as the answer. It's up to you whether you add the email notification or not - what are your requirements? If you do decide to do it, either do it inside the `if` statement (before the `continue`), or if you don't want to spam yourself, add the server name to a list and then email the list at the end.

Comment: Will do alroc.  Thanks again for the help!